# location accuracy javascript navigator.geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location, maps

I have noticed that when using google.maps location you can track the location of your car or walking very closely. Yet when I try this of code in javascript:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    success,
    error, {
        maximumAge: 600000,
        timeout: 10000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    });
```

It returns success with an accuracy of 800m --> 1200m (meters) I must be totally wrong on how to accurately track location in javascript. I will be using window.setInterval( to update the position continuously! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use watchPosition() instead of repeatedly calling getCurrentPosition().

You can also use position.coords.accuracy to decide if the reading is accurate enough for you to use. The value is in meters and can be thought of as a radius of a circle and you're in there somewhere.

If you want to spend the time/effort you can also provide a sophisticated filter and sanity checker such as: -

```
'use strict';
/* identification division.
 * program-id.    TravelManagerPolyfill.
 * author.        Richard Maher.
 * version.       1.0
 */

// Simple polyfill paper-tiger
ServiceWorkerRegistration.prototype.travelManager 
        = new BackgroundGeolocation();
/*
 * This module simulates the work that needs to be done by the UA or
 * SW daemon in order to facilitate background geolocation on the web.
 *
 * Each client even in the same scope will have their own TravelManager
 * object/registration. With individual "options" configuration.
 *
 * TODO: Ask someone why registrations just can't be done in Ultimate
 * Web App manifests?
 *
 * NB: Please treat this as a black-box and concentrate on what it does
 * and not how it does it. Most of the magic will be in the UA. Some of
 * the proposed throttle functionality may be duplicating existing UA 
 * functionality and therefore be redundant.
 */
function BackgroundGeolocation() 
{
const EARTH_RADIUS     = 6371000;
const SHUSH            =   60000;
const NUMBER           = "number";
const STRING           = "string";
const BOOLEAN          = "boolean";
const DATE             = "date";
const MIN_DATE         =   -864*Math.pow(10,13);
const MAX_DATE         =    864*Math.pow(10,13);
const MSECS            =   1000;    
const TIMEOUT_IS_USELESS
                       = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
const toRad            = function(num){return num*Math.PI/180};

const DEFAULT_OPTIONS  = 
{
    "maxSilence" : 900000,
    "minSilence" :   4000,
    "maxSnail"   :  15000,
    "minProgress":     15,
    "maxAge"     :      0,
    "accurate"   :   true,
    "dropDodgy"  :  false
}
var options     = DEFAULT_OPTIONS;
var lastOptions = options; 
var seqNum      = 0;

var lastPos, trackerId, loiterTimer, deltaMetres, lastDrop, 
    replayTimer, timeDetent, spaceDetent, loiterDetent, 
    maxLocAge, accurate, maxSilence, watchCnt, acceptCnt,
    lastUpdate, kept, broken, currActive, regId, subscription,
    dropDodgy, mostConfident, leastConfident, recalibrateTimer
    ;

var OptionElem = function(name,valType,minValue,maxValue,shift)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.type = valType;
    this.minValue = minValue;
    this.maxValue = maxValue;
    this.shift = shift;
    return this;
}

var optionRules = 
    [
    new OptionElem("maxSilence", NUMBER, 0,Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,MSECS),
    new OptionElem("minSilence", NUMBER, 0,SHUSH,MSECS),
    new OptionElem("maxSnail",   NUMBER, 0,Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,MSECS),
    new OptionElem("maxAge",     NUMBER, 0,Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,MSECS),
    new OptionElem("minProgress",NUMBER, 0,Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,1),
    new OptionElem("accurate",   BOOLEAN,0,1,0),
    new OptionElem("dropDodgy",  BOOLEAN,0,1,0),
    ];


var subscribe =     
    function(userOptions) 
    {                                   
        if(!navigator.geolocation) 
            return Promise.reject(new Error("Unsupported browser - No Geolocation support"));

        if (regId) return Promise.resolve(subscription);

        if (userOptions != undefined) {
            parseOptions(userOptions);
            lastOptions = options;          
        }

        regId = ++seqNum;   

        subscription = 
            {
                getId: function(){return regId},
                setOptions: setOptions,
                unsubscribe: unsubscribe
            }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
                    {
                        kept   = resolve;
                        broken = reject;
                        getCurrent(startPosition, startError);
                    }); 
    }               

var getCurrent = 
    function(currentSuccess, currentFailure) 
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(currentSuccess, currentFailure ,{
                    maximumAge: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
                    timeout: TIMEOUT_IS_USELESS
                });                             
    }

var startPosition =
    function(position)
    {
        kept(subscription);
        kept   = null;
        broken = null;
        fireTravelEvent({
                        "cmd":"start",
                        "position": pos4Net(position)
                        },function(){
                                lastPos        = position;
                                watchCnt       = 1;
                                acceptCnt      = 0;
                                mostConfident  = position.coords.accuracy.toFixed();
                                leastConfident = mostConfident;
                                startWatch();
                                loiterTimer  = setTimeout(loiterLimit, loiterDetent);
                        })
    }

var startError =
    function(positionError){
        regId = null;
        broken(positionError);
        broken = null;
        kept   = null;
    }

var startWatch =
    function()
    {
        trackerId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(filterLocation, locError, {
                    enableHighAccuracy: accurate,
                    maximumAge: maxLocAge,
                    timeout: TIMEOUT_IS_USELESS
                });

        recalibrateTimer = setTimeout(recalibrate, maxSilence);                 
    }

var stopWatch = 
    function()
    {                               
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(trackerId);
        clearTimeout(recalibrateTimer);

        trackerId        = null;
        recalibrateTimer = null;
    }

var fireTravelEvent = 
    function(msg,callback)
    {
        try {
            currActive.postMessage(msg);
            console.log("Msg Sent to SW");
            if (callback) callback();
        } catch (e) {
            if (e.name == "InvalidStateError" || e.name == "TypeError") {
                navigator.serviceWorker.ready
                .then(reg => {
                        currActive = reg.active;
                        fireTravelEvent(msg, callback)})
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }   

var vetOption = function(userOption,rule)
{       
    var result;
    switch(rule.type){
        case NUMBER:
        case DATE:
            result = Number(userOption*rule.shift);
            if (Number.isNaN(result) || result < rule.minValue || result > rule.maxValue) {
                result = null;
            } 
            break;
        case STRING:
            result = String(userOption);
            if (typeof result != STRING){
                result = null;
            }
            break;
        case BOOLEAN:
            result = Boolean(userOption);
            if (typeof result != BOOLEAN){
                result = null;
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Invalid data type '"+rule.type+"'")
    }
    if (result == null) {
        console.log("Invalid parameter '"+rule.name+"'")            
    }
    return result;
}

var setOptions =
    function(userOptions)
    {
        parseOptions(userOptions);

        for (var x in options) {
            if (options[x] != lastOptions[x]){
                stopWatch();
                startWatch();
                break;
            }
        }

        lastOptions = options;          
    }

var parseOptions =
    function(userOptions)
    {           
        var rawOptions = userOptions || {};
        for (var i=0; i<optionRules.length; i++){
            var currOption = optionRules[i].name;
            if ((currOption in rawOptions)){
                var currentTarget = vetOption(rawOptions[currOption], optionRules[i]);
                if (currentTarget){
                    options[currOption] = currentTarget;
                } else {
                    console.log("Invalid option "+optionRules[i].name+" value = " + rawOptions[currOption])
                }
            }
        }

        for (var opt in rawOptions){
            if (!optionRules.some(function(rule){return rule.name==this},opt)){
                console.log("Unknown option '"+opt+"'")
            }
        }

        timeDetent    = options.minSilence;         
        maxSilence    = options.maxSilence;         
        spaceDetent   = options.minProgress;
        loiterDetent  = options.maxSnail;
        maxLocAge     = options.maxAge;
        accurate      = options.accurate;
        dropDodgy     = options.dropDodgy;

        if (timeDetent > maxSilence){
            timeDetent = maxSilence;
            console.log("Minimum Silence overridden by Maximum Silence");
        }           
        if (loiterDetent > maxSilence){
            loiterDetent = maxSilence;
            console.log("Maximum Snail overridden by Maximum Silence");
        }           
        if (loiterDetent < timeDetent) {
            loiterDetent = timeDetent;
            console.log("Maximum Snail overridden by Minimum Silence");
        }

        return;
    }

var locError = 
    function(error) 
    {           
        fireTravelEvent({"cmd":"error","error": {
                            "code": error.code,
                            "message": error.message
                            }});
    }

var recalibrate = 
    function()
    {
        console.log("recalibrating");

        stopWatch();
        startWatch();

        mostConfident = leastConfident;
    }

var filterLocation = 
    function(position) 
    {
        watchCnt++;

        if (position.timestamp <= lastPos.timestamp) return;

        var currTime = Date.now();
        var updateDelta = currTime - lastUpdate;
        var dropping = (updateDelta < timeDetent);

        deltaMetres = calculateDistance(
                    position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude,
                    lastPos.coords.latitude,
                    lastPos.coords.longitude)

        if (deltaMetres.toFixed() < spaceDetent) return;

        if (dropping) {
            lastDrop = position;
            if (!replayTimer) 
                replayTimer = setTimeout(moveReplay, (timeDetent - updateDelta));
            return;
        }

        var giveOrTake = position.coords.accuracy.toFixed();            
        if (giveOrTake > leastConfident) leastConfident = giveOrTake;
        if (giveOrTake < mostConfident ) mostConfident  = giveOrTake;

        if (dropDodgy                   &&
            giveOrTake > spaceDetent    &&
            giveOrTake > deltaMetres    &&
            giveOrTake > (2*mostConfident)) {
            return; // Not legit. Dicky phone tower or access point?
        }              

        acceptCnt++;

        clearTimeout(recalibrateTimer);
        recalibrateTimer = setTimeout(recalibrate, maxSilence);

        clearTimeout(loiterTimer);
        loiterTimer = setTimeout(loiterLimit, loiterDetent);

        fireTravelEvent({
                        "cmd":"travel",
                        "position":pos4Net(position)
                        })

        lastPos = position;
        lastUpdate = currTime;
    }

var loiterLimit = 
    function()
    {
        loiterTimer = null;
        fireTravelEvent({"cmd":"loiter","position":pos4Net(lastPos)})
    }

var moveReplay =
    function()
    {
        replayTimer = null;

        if ((lastDrop.timestamp > lastPos.timestamp)) {
            filterLocation(lastDrop);
        }                       
    }           

var calculateDistance =
    function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
        var dLat = toRad(lat2 - lat1);
        var dLon = toRad(lon2 - lon1);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(toRad(lat1)) * 
                Math.cos(toRad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        var distance = EARTH_RADIUS * 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        return distance;
    }

var unsubscribe =       
    function(cancel) 
    {                           
        if (!regId) return Promise.resolve(false);

        stopWatch();

        if (loiterTimer) {
            clearTimeout(loiterTimer);
            loiterTimer = null;
        }

        if (replayTimer) {
            clearTimeout(replayTimer);
            replayTimer = null;
        }

        regId = null;
        lastUpdate = 0;

        if (cancel) {
            return Promise.resolve(true);
        } else {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
                        {
                            kept   = resolve;
                            broken = reject;
                            getCurrent(endPosition, endError);
                        }); 
        }           
    }   

var endPosition = 
    function(position) 
    {           
        fireTravelEvent({
                        "cmd":"end",
                        "position":pos4Net(position)
                        })
        kept(true);
        kept   = null;
        broken = null;
    }

var endError = 
    function(error) 
    {           
        fireTravelEvent({"cmd":"error","error": {
                            "code": error.code,
                            "message": error.message
                            }});
        broken(false);
        broken = null;
        kept   = null;
    }

var pos4Net = 
    function(pos)
    {
        return {
            coords: {
                latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
                accuracy: pos.coords.accuracy.toFixed()
            },
            timestamp: pos.timestamp
        }
    }

return {subscribe: subscribe};
}
```

Comment: Hi McMurphy, thanks for your help with this!, I will look at this soon, do you think it is as accurate as google.maps is ? The position on google maps I get on my phone while outside is very near perfect, but not even close with my code. Which is kind of what I was trying for, but as mentioned could not even get close.

Comment: It is accurate "enough" try watchPosition and see the results. I certainly do believe that Google has some algorythm than hones the GPS.

Comment: See https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen for a working example route trace.